# Pascal and Brianchon's theorems generalized for hyperbolic paraboloid

Tags: projective-geometry, analytic-geometry, quadrics

I know that giving a general version of these two theorems for quadrics can be quite tricky, but if we restrict ourselves to a verssion that holds for the hyperbolic paraboloid only it should be possible to give a more accessible formulation. At least that's what I was discussing today with some friends who do Geometry, ¿How would one who is not specialized in geometry formulate (and if possible, sketch a proof of) these?

Comment: This question might be more useful to others if you gave a more thorough background, defining your terms and describing what you don't like about the general version of these theorems more precisely.

Comment: What I mean is that if I want to explain this to my students, whose only background is two semesters of college maths, a version for all quadrics is just too advanced.

Comment: http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/ may be a better forum for a question like this.

Comment: Is this question related to [that one on Math SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1208480/35416)? The title sounds very similar, but the text is quite different, as is the name of the poster.